# JSON serialization in WCF - Are object properties ordered alphabetically?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have created a WCF REST service that returns JSON, but the properties in the objects that are serialized are returned alphabetically.

Is there any way I change this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting the order property on your data members for your data contracts:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyClass
{
     [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 1)]
     public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you accept the answer, then?  ;^D (Looks like fr3d's still around on stackoverflow).